# Should you print the stacktrace if you catch a known error(Exception)?

Tags: java, exception

If I use JpaRepository as an example here in a spring-boot application.
I have the usual Controller -> Service -> Repository layers.
Lets say I want to save something to the database and this item already exist (e. g. DataIntegrityViolationException is thrown because I created a unique constraint between a few columns).

So lets say this is thrown. This is an expected behaviour if the user tries to save an object that already have the exact data and is already stored in the database.

My question here is: Should I print the stacktrace or just do a basic logger.error("An item already exists with the same values that you try to save").

I can't find best practices on this.
My thought is that this is a known error and I know what went wrong, so I don't need the stacktrace. It just spams the log with extra lines of code.

Any good pointers?

Comment: I would do both **logger.error("An item already exists with the same values that you try to save", e)** . In this way you know that it is a known exception and you will have the stack trace as well so you don't need to search for a class and method which is throwing the exception.

Comment: Just log a detailed enough message. Maybe with all the input values. Imagine someone else trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: @NullPointer The classname is already in the log. I know where it goes wrong i know why JpaRepository threw that error, I don't need to follow the stacktrace.
The question was more, should it be logged as info or as error? But SonarQube wants a stacktrace with error.

Comment: Definitely not as a info since your commit (Saving record to DB) operation has failed. If you don't want to log it as a error, add it as a warning ( **logger.warn** ) so by seeing the logs you know that certain record has not been inserted.

Comment: Thank you! how could I just ignore warn

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why do you want to ignore warnings?

Comment: I'm sorry. I ment: how could I forget that warning existed. I was just thinking of error and info. I guess warn is the proper way to log it.

Comment: I will add my comment comment as an answer to this question so it will be helpful to others as well. You may mark my answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do both logger.error("An item already exists with the same values that you try to save", e) .
In this way you know that it is a known exception and you will have the stack trace as well
so you don't need to search for a class and method which is throwing the exception.

*OP: @NullPointer The classname is already in the log. I know where it goes wrong i know why JpaRepository threw that error, I don't need to follow the stacktrace.
 The question was more, should it be logged as info or as error?
 But SonarQube wants a stacktrace with error.*

Definitely not as a info since your commit (Saving record to DB) operation has failed. 
If you don't want to log it as a error, add it as a warning ( logger.warn ) 
so by seeing the logs you know that certain record has not been inserted.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an expected behavior, catch the exception and do something sensible and don't log an error. If you decide that you want to log an error, include the stack trace. It is frustrating to find errors in the logs that you can't fix (and this seems to be one?) and it is also irritating to find errors in the logs without enough details.

Of course, if you re-throw the exception don't forget to include the original (pass it to the constructor).

Comment: Thank you, we do rethrow but some people also log an error and not include it when rethrowing.

This ends up with us working in different ways and I want us all to work the same way. I could be the one who's wrong in this question, but I really want to do it right and not have everyone work the same way but then end up doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a exception handler for your entire application that should catch the exceptions, log them, and return response of the API with status and message. You should check out `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` class provided by spring boot for this same purpose.
This is the official doc on this class

> A convenient base class for {@link ControllerAdvice @ControllerAdvice} classes that wish to provide centralized
>   exception handling across all {@code @RequestMapping} methods
>   through {@code @ExceptionHandler} methods.

Comment: Thank you, we already do this with ControllerAdvice.
Then thing is we catch the exceptions thrown by JpaRepository and throw it as our  own custom exception that is caught in the ControllerAdvice that responds with the correct message.

The question still stands though, should I log it as an error if it's a know exception or just logger.info("The object already exists") and then throw my own exception that returns a ResponseEntitty to the end user.